# Magento 2.3.2: Authorize.Net: An error occurred during processing. Please try again

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, error, payment-methods, authorize.net

I'm trying to place order via `Authorize.Net [Sandbox Account]`, but sadly I'm not able to, I'm getting error like: `An error occurred during processing. Please try again.` OR `Error, message: code: "E00003", text: Root element is missing.`, also I'm getting some errors in console you can see those in below images.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, I am facing same problem in same magneto version 
Have you got any solution?

Comment: @KarangarMeghnathi Yes i got my solution....

Comment: @PartabSaifuddinZakir i am facing same issue in magento 2.3.3. Can you please tell me what is the solution? Thanks

Comment: @Hardik Did you have any third party or custom module installed in your magento 2 ?

Comment: @PartabSaifuddinZakir what is the solution for this? please say , i am also getting same error

Comment: @StevenHarris Disable all Custom also Third Party module and check if error exist...

Comment: Paging DenverCoder9...